# Insert dash into the output of jq at specific positions

Tags: format, jq

How do I modify the jq code in:

```
echo '{"date":"20200101"}{"date":"20210101"}' | jq -r '"The bus will be here on \( .date ), at ten o clock"'
```

to change the format of the date from eg `20200101` into `2020-01-01`?

I get the output:

```
The bus will be here on 20200101, at ten o clock
The bus will be here on 20210101, at ten o clock
```

I want the output:

```
The bus will be here on 2020-01-01, at ten o clock
The bus will be here on 2021-01-01, at ten o clock
```

I tried:

```
echo '{"date":"20200101"}{"date":"20210101"}' | jq -r '"The bus will be here on \( .date | strftime("%Y-%m-%d") ), at ten o clock"'
```

but that tells me:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): strftime/1 requires parsed datetime inputs
```

`strftime` apparently needs the input date to be in another format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), the format for `strftime` is:

> The format strings for strptime and strftime are described in typical C library documentation. The format string for ISO 8601 datetime is "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ".

which is why your expression errors, since the input does not match the required format.

In this case, you should simply slice the string:

```bash
echo '{"date":"20200101"}{"date":"20210101"}' | jq -r '"The bus will be here on \( .date | .[0:4] + "-" + .[4:6] + "-" + .[6:8] ), at ten o clock"'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `strptime` to first parse the `%Y%m%d`-formatted date, then re-format it with `strftime` to, for example, `%F`:

```bash
… | jq -r '"The bus will be here on \(.date | strptime("%Y%m%d") | strftime("%F")), at ten o clock"'
```

```
The bus will be here on 2020-01-01, at ten o clock
The bus will be here on 2021-01-01, at ten o clock
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WiPUEOJLMKl)